# Getting "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'location_y' referenced before assignment" even though it's not

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to create a D&D map viewer (so if that I can make the map interactive) but for some reason I keep getting "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'location_y' referenced before assignment" and "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'location_x' referenced before assignment" and it doesn't make any sense to me so what do I need to add or change to make this work?

Code:

```
import PIL.Image
from PIL import ImageTk
from tkinter import *

location_x = 0
location_y = 0
scroll_wheel = 1

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=1920, height=1080)
canvas.pack()

file_name = ("MAP_X" + str(location_x) + "_Y" + str(location_y) + ".png")

def onKeyPress(event):
    if(event.char == "a"):
        location_x -= 1
        if(location_x == -1):
            done_check_x = 0
            while(done_check_x == 0):
                if(PIL.Image.open("MAP_X" + str(location_x) + "_Y" + str(location_y) + ".png")):
                    location_x += 1
                else:
                    location_x -= 1
                    done_check_x = 1

    elif(event.char == "d"):
        location_x += 1
        if not (PIL.Image.open("MAP_X" + str(location_x) + "_Y" + str(location_y) + ".png")):
            location_x = 0

    elif(event.char == "w"):
        location_y -= 1
        if(location_y == -1):
            done_check_y = 0
            while(done_check_y == 0):
                if(PIL.Image.open("MAP_X" + str(location_x) + "_Y" + str(location_y) + ".png")):
                    location_y += 1
                else:
                    location_y -= 1
                    done_check_y = 1
    
    elif(event.char == "s"):
        location_y += 1
        if not (PIL.Image.open("MAP_X" + str(location_x) + "_Y" + str(location_y) + ".png")):
            location_y = 0

root.bind('<KeyPress>', onKeyPress)

while(root):
    file_name = ("MAP_X" + str(location_x) + "_Y" + str(location_y) + ".png")
    img = PIL.Image.open(file_name)
    resized_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img.resize((1920 * scroll_wheel, 1080 * scroll_wheel)))
    canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=resized_img)
    
    mainloop()

#with Image.open("MAP_X" + str(start_location_x) + "_Y" + str(start_location_y) + ".png") as img:
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The traceback should have told you the line the problem was on. It would be helpful if you included that. Just include the entire traceback, it's good practice.

Without seeing that I'll suggest you might want to declare `global location_x, location_y, etc...` inside your `onKeyPress()` function.

Comment: @brunson oh yeah sorry its on these lines:
33, 28, 44, and 17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
def onKeyPress(event):
    if(event.char == "a"):
```

To this:

```
def onKeyPress(event):
    global location_x, location_y, scroll_wheel

    if(event.char == "a"):
```

Comment: Okay I did that but I don't think it's globally changing the location_x and location_y variables because the images would then change because I have 3 files MAP_X0_Y0.png MAP_X0_Y1.png and MAP_X1_Y0.png

And I plan to add more images later

Answer (score 1):

No, you actually try to reference a **local** variables `location_x` and `location_y`, which are not existent (so that's why `-=` operator in you case raises this exception, you can't modify variable that doesn't yet exist).

In your code both `location_x` and `location_y` are **global** variables, and to modify them you **have to explicitly** note that. To do that, simply declare that you are working with global variables in your function like so:

```py
x = 0
y = 0

def func():
    global x, y 
    x -= 1
    y -= 1
```